# Does Silverlight support StringFormat in binding?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I know that WPF 3.5 SP1 supports a `StringFormat` in a binding, but can Silverlight do the same? I thought it could, but damned if I can make it work!

Here's a snippet of my XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime, StringFormat=t}" />
```

It compiles OK, but I get a runtime error when it gets to the browser...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Silverlight 3 and below do not, but you can use a Value Converter and specify the ConverterParamenter in the binding.  You'll have to create your own Value Converter by deriving a class from IValueConverter like I've shown [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/synergist/archive/2008/07/30/using-a-converterparameter-in-a-silverlight-2-value-converter.aspx).

Silverlight 4 and later has the same StringFormat binding property as WPF.

Answer (score 37):

I don't know which version of Silverlight introduced it, but you now can. I'm using Silverlight 4 Beta.

```
   <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" 
     Binding="{Binding CreateDt, StringFormat=\{0:d\}}" />
```

http://blog.davemdavis.net/2009/12/silverlight-4-data-binding-string.html

Here's info on [Formatting Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy(v=VS.95).aspx), and more for [DateTime](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/).

Here's full documentation on [Silverlight Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072(VS.95).aspx).

Comment: The relevant reference says only supported in Silverlight 4 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat%28VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: Incidentally, Tim Heuer points out a bug and workaround with the StringFormat binding when used with non-US cultures: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/11/stringformat-and-currentculture-in-silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The string format noted by Simon is in Silverlight 4.  There is even support in Blend for setting the format.