# Silverlight 3 Binding with a little change

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, binding, silverlight-3.0

Let's say I have class with Name property. I'd like to bind collection of objects of this class to Silverlight 3 ListBox. But I want to show items like that:

- "Some dynamic str " + Name (object property)
- "Some dynamic str " + Name (object property)
- "Some dynamic str " + Name (object property)

How can I achieve this without use of converters?

Can I use function for each item to format display value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight 3 does NOT support the StringFormat Binding option: [Does Silverlight support StringFormat in binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398353/does-silverlight-support-stringformat-in-binding)

You could use a ValueConverter but if you do not want that as mentioned in your question you might want to consider either:

Changing the ViewModel property so it returns the correct text or

adding extra TextBlocks in the View that prefix the text with "Some str".