# How can we display amount with $ symbol in silverlight bar chart on any axis.?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-3.0

Hi I am using a bar chart in silverlight in my application to show the total bill amount(Y axis) per month(on x axis), I am able to display that if i display amount as a number but I want to show it with a $ preceeding the amount value..any help is appreciated .thanks..

Comment: SL3 I don't think supports `StringFormat` (also for William's to work in SL4+ you'd need to remove the `''` and just make it `StringFormat=C` or it would make the letter `C` literal and display like C12345). Refer to this similar question about using a converter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398353/does-silverlight-support-stringformat-in-binding

Comment: Sorry, I come from a SL4+/Win8 side: assumptions. Darn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use StringFormat in the binding. Say:

```
<... Value="{Binding Value, StringFormat='C'}" ... />
```

This will [format the number as currency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), and will be culture sensitive, too.

Comment: @ William, the following is my block of code i am very new to silverlight technology, i unabe to use this value property in my cpntrols.. <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">                                    
                                      
                                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedContent}"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60" />                                       
                                    </ControlTemplate>